# Choosing dice out of a box

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

In a box, we have $5$ dice. Three of them are proper, one has two sixes, and a second one has six sixes.

We’re given the events

- $A$: after the first throw, we have a six.
- $B$: after the next two throws, we have six and something else.

We want to find the probability $$P(A \cap B \mid \text{proper dice}).$$

My attempt is:
$$ (1/6)\times(1/6)\times(5/6)=\left(5/6^3\right).$$
I know that this is the wrong answer. The question is, why?

Comment: The probability calculation will not be hard if we know what $A$ and $B$ mean. $A$ is fairly clear. For $B$, are we tossing a total of three times? And if we are, does six and something else refer to the last two throws? If this is a textbook question, I find it hard to believe that the specification would be so unclear.  And what are the funny dice doing if the question is about proper dice? Do you actually want the probability of proper given $A\cap B$?

Comment: Yes B is about tossing a total of three times. In a first throw we have for certain 6 in latter two we can have either six and something  or something and six (order does not matter).

Comment: The probability of $A\cap B$ given that we are using a proper die is $\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{10}{36}$.

Comment: I first thought that $B$ was a six on second worp and something else on last worp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General speaking for two events $A$ and $C$: 
$$\mathbb{P}(A \mid C) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(C)}.$$

So you calculated $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B \cap \textrm{ proper dice})$, so you must still divide by the probability of picking a proper dice.

To be more precise, you need to consider your event space $\Omega$, which can be given as 
$$ \Omega = \{1, 2,3,4,5,6\}^3 \times \{1,2,3,4,5\}.$$
Here the tuple $(x,y,z,a)$ means: first roll is $x$, second roll is $y$, third roll is $z$ and the dice is number $a$.
Now, you need to find a probability function on this space, which is given by
$$\mathbb{P}((x,y,z,a)) =\left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{5\cdot 6^3} & a \in \{1,2,3\}  \\ \frac{1}{5\cdot 6^3} & a=4 \textrm{ and } x,y,z\in\{1,2,3,4\} \\ \frac{2}{5\cdot6^3} &a=4 \textrm{ and only one of }x,y,z \textrm{ is } 6 \\ \frac{4}{5 \cdot 6^3} & a =4 \textrm{ and only two of }x,y,z \textrm{ are } 6 \\ \frac{8}{5\cdot6^3} & a=4 \textrm{ and } x=y=z=6 \\\frac{1}{5} &a=5 \textrm{ and } x=y=z=6\end{matrix}\right.$$

Now, what is the event of first a $6$ and then exactly one $6$ in the last two throws and a fair dice? That is $\{(6,y,z,a) \mid a \in \{1,2,3\} \textrm{ and exactly one of} y,z \textrm{ is }6\}$, which has probability $3 \cdot \binom{2}{1} \frac{1 \cdot 1 \cdot 5}{5 \cdot 6^3} = \frac{6}{6^3}$. Here the $\binom{2}{1}$  is because the last two throws can first be a $6$, or first be something else.
The event a fair dice is $\{ (x,y,z,a ) \mid a \in \{ 1,2,3\}\}$ which has probability $\frac{3}{5}$, which gives a conditional expectation of $\frac{10}{6^3}$.

Comment: Still i think it does not hold because then $(5/6^3)\times(5/3)=\frac{5^2}{6^3\times3} \ne (10/6^3)$ because know $(10/6^3)$  is the answer

Comment: Could it be about choices? That we do not know the order of six and the other number i.e. it may be six and something else as well as something else and then six?

Comment: Making a edit, almost done

Comment: It has to do with the order of the outcomes

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough answer :), appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to make a detour through conditional probabilities. Given that proper dice are used for each throw, the probability of $A\cap B$ can be calculated directly, much as you tried to. Your only error was to omit the factor of $2$ that arises because in $B$ the six can come on either of two throws. If you include this, you directly obtain the result $10\cdot6^{-3}$ obtained in the accepted answer.